# Sixth from last? pro pre ante pen ult

Tags: word-usage, latin

There is a latin sequence of terms that refer to order from last:

- ultimate, last
- [**pen**ultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penultimate#English), second from last
- [**ante**penultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antepenultimate), third from last
- [**pre**antepenultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preantepenultimate#English), forth from last
- [**pro**preantepenultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propreantepenultimate#English), fifth from last
- **xxx**propreantepenultimate, sixth from last?

Has the final word ever been used or coined anywhere?

Comment: Some might claim that the process is productive: you need more fairly useless terms to label syllables in the words you keep generating. But I think you've run out of candidate prefixes.

Comment: ELU is about at least semi-normal English usage. If you have a question about one-off coinages in literature or comedy, you might be better asking elsewhere.

Comment: I hope no-one answers this, because we all know what the next question would be . . .

Answer (score 6):

**No, there isn't**.

Anyone can coin a prospective new word but is it going to be current usage? Will it ever find its way into a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Prepropreantepenultimate
This is what I propose for sixth from last.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Goole has a reference to it! https://tvline.com/what-to-watch/jamie-foxx-day-shift-movie-netflix-streaming/.  Since everything on the internet is always true, the word already exists.